# $0^\infty$ and indeterminate forms

Tags: calculus, limits, indeterminate-forms

I have actually two related questions:
**1.** Should indeterminate forms be able to attain an infinite number of values to be considered indeterminate?
I’m asking because [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form#Expressions_that_are_not_indeterminate_forms) says:

> The expression
> 1/0 is not commonly regarded as an indeterminate form, because there is not an infinite range of values that
> f/g could approach.

**2.** I know that $0^\infty$ is not indeterminate.
But i want to know why this is wrong:
$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,\infty)}x^y=e^{y\cdot \ln(x)}$ and if we take the path $y=\frac{a}{\ln(x)}$ it becomes $e^a$ and could attain infinite number of values and therefore is indeterminate.

Comment: $a$ is not arbitrary, $a=y\ln x \to -\infty$ with the given conditions.

Comment: Also keep in mind that if you think about a limiting procedure, $0^{\infty}$ could be thought of as something like the limit of $\big(\frac{1}{h}\big)^h$. Eventually the base is going to be less than $1$ and the exponent will be quite large. The power (bigger than 1) of a number between $0$ and $1$ will be smaller than itself, and you can do basic limiting arguments from there. *This does not however mean an infinite product of numbers between $0$ and $1$ will necessarily tend to $0$*. The key is that the number you're multiplying by itself $\big(\frac{1}{h}\big)$ is bounded away from $1$.

Comment: If I could, I'd excommunicate everybody using "indeterminate form". If there is a limit, and we can calculate it, what exactly is "indeterminate", then? And if there ain't (as in this case), "indeterminate" would sum that up nicely, without being all too useful, naturally.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: Sign me up for excommunication! It is useful to explain that some "infinity arithmetic" expressions make sense and others don't. There is a straightforward method to determine which does and which doesn't, which goes like this: (1) substitute a variable for each constant sub-expression (finite or infinite); (2) write the corresponding limit symbol in front; (3) and ask yourself whether the limit exists.

Comment: You can prove that some such limits exist, thereby proving general infinity arithmetic equations like $(+\infty) + (+\infty) = +\infty$, and you can prove that other such limits don't exist such as the one that comes from $(+\infty) - (+\infty)$. That's why $(+\infty) + (+\infty)$ is a determinate form, whereas $(+\infty) - (+\infty)$ is indeterminate.

Comment: @Lee Mosher Well, if you can't sense the contradiction between your "There is a straightforward method to *determine*" and "in*determinate* form", I really can't help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that as $x\to 0$ then $y:=a/\ln(x)\to 0$, so what you have written is a justification of $0^0$ being indeterminate.

Whatever path we take, $0^\infty$ will give $0$: this is because if $y\geq 1$ and $0<x<1$ then $0<x^y\leq x$.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:$$0^\infty=(\exp-\infty)^\infty=\exp(-\infty\times\infty)=\exp(-\infty)=0.$$Long answer: suppose $f(x) \to0^+,\,g(x)\to\infty$ as $x\to c$. Then$$\ln f\to-\infty\implies g\ln f\to-\infty\implies f^g\to0.$$